# SQL query to remove HTML inputs from the database that vary on URL's

Tags: html, mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm using Wordpress and I want to hard remove all inputs from my posts (wp_posts table), but since each input has a diferent url, I have no idea the query to remove them all at once.

Is there a way to remove a string that starts with `<input` and everything inside the first `/>`?

For example

```
update wp_posts set post_content =
replace(post_content,'select everything that starts with <input and remove everything until the first /> after <input','');
```

Comment: I don't think you can do like this, but what you can do is get all posts, loop through each post, filter the content from get_the_content() and update db using post id which will be unique

Comment: But this way, how will I remove the inputs? Isn't there a way to add a wildcard on SQL?

Comment: That's what i said, get the contents filter it and update back the filtered contents to db

Answer (score 0):

There's still time?

In MYSQL above 5.5, you can use the xml function ExtractValue :

```
SELECT ExtractValue(field, '//text()') FROM table;
```

Se a example below:
[image]

More about this function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue